# Where are the locations of all of the Name Raters?

Tags: pokemon-series

In each game, there is a name rater somewhere. Where are all of them? I only know where one of them is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Pokémon Name Raters can be found in the following locations:
>
> - South of Mr. Fuji's house in Lavender Town in Kanto
> - North of the Magnet Train station in Goldenrod City in Johto
> - South of the Contest HallRS/Battle TentE in Slateport City in Hoenn
> - Inside the Day Care in Agate Village in Orre
> - First floor of Eterna Condominiums in Eterna City in Sinnoh
> - Castelia City in Unova
> - Inside the left building north of Central Plaza in Black and White
> - Inside the Medal offices in Black 2 and White 2
> - Inside the Pokémon Center of Camphrier Town in Kalos

[Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Name_Rater)